# Binary Search Tree insert function in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, binary-search-tree

Suppose we want to insert value smaller. It will go to `Node (insert x left, k, right)` 
I don't understand how we can have `insert x left` when function insert is declared as taking only one argument, the key. How can left also be passed to insert funtion?

```
type 'a bst_t =  
| Leaf
| Node of 'a bst_t * 'a * 'a bst_t

let rec insert x = function  
  | Leaf -> Node (Leaf, x, Leaf) 
  | Node (left, k, right) ->
    if x < k then Node (insert x left, k, right) 
    else Node (left, k, insert x right)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ocaml has a REPL, i.e. an interactive environment useful for experimenting and *having a conversation with ocaml*.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.3

# type 'a bst_t =
| Leaf
| Node of 'a bst_t * 'a * 'a bst_t    ;;
type 'a bst_t = Leaf | Node of 'a bst_t * 'a * 'a bst_t
# let rec insert x = function
  | Leaf -> Node (Leaf, x, Leaf)
  | Node (left, k, right) ->
    if x < k then Node (insert x left, k, right)
    else Node (left, k, insert x right)         ;;
val insert : 'a -> 'a bst_t -> 'a bst_t = <fun>
```

The read-eval-print-loop shows not only the value of the evaluated expression but also its type. Here, you can see that the symbol `insert` is bound to a function which takes a value of "some type `'a`" and returns another function that takes a value of "a binary tree of that type `'a`" and returns a value of the same binary tree of `'a` type.

I strongly recommend to use REPLs whenever you have them, as they tell you a lot about the system.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`utop`](https://github.com/diml/utop) as a REPL. It's easy to install with the help of [OPAM](https://opam.ocaml.org): `opam install utop`. Or at least wrap `ocaml` into something like [`rlwrap`](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) or [`ledit`](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~ddr/ledit/) (more details and tips can be found [here](http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/wiki.cocan.org/tips_for_using_the_ocaml_toplevel.html)).

Answer (score 0):

The `function` keyword defines a function as a series of patterns, and is almost always used without giving the parameter a name as such. So the `insert` function actually has two parameters.

This definition without `function` is equivalent:

```
let rec insert x node =
  match node with
  | Leaf -> Node (Leaf, x, Leaf) 
  | Node (left, k, right) ->
    if x < k then Node (insert x left, k, right) 
    else Node (left, k, insert x right)
```

Comment: Does that mean i could actually pass it an arbitrary number of arguments?

Comment: No, the function takes two arguments exactly. (Look at the equivalent form, the arguments are explicit.)

Comment: _without naming the parameter_ - maybe you want to make it easier for a beginner, but this hurts. I would say "naming the single parameter or start pattern matching on it" if I do not want to talk about pattern matching left of the equal sign.

Comment: I see what you're saying. You can name the parameter with `function`, but it's not commonly useful to do this. Also, you don't have to name the parameter with `fun`, you can use a pattern. Something to explain to beginning programmers later on, I think. I can add the word "commonly" to the description.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might seem so at first sight, function `insert` has not one but two arguments - one is the key to be inserted as you said, and the second one is the bst_t in which you want to insert the key.

In OCaml, the concept of [Point-free programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) is highly recommended when it's possible to apply it, and that's precisely what happens with your insert function. Your version of the function is just a short-hand notation for the following function (written in normal, verbose syntax):

```
let rec insert x bst = match bst with 
| Leaf -> Node (Leaf, x, Leaf) 
| Node (left, k, right) ->
  if x < k then Node (insert x left, k, right) 
  else Node (left, k, insert x right)
```

where bst is the tree on which the insertion is performed, i.e. the tree that the function matches the `Leaf | Node` patterns against.